# Need help fixing the alignment with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class app extends JFrame{
  public app(String title){
    super(title);

    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("First Name:");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l1);

    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Last Name:");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l2, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l2);

    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Street:");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l3, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l3);

    JLabel l4 = new JLabel("City:");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l4, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l4);

    JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Province:");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l5, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l5);

    JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Postal Code:");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 5;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l6, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l6);

    JLabel l7 = new JLabel("Home Phone:");
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l7, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l7);

    JLabel l8 = new JLabel("Cell Phone:");
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l8, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l8);

    JLabel l9 = new JLabel("Email Address:");
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l9, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l9);

    JLabel l10 = new JLabel("Age:");
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l10, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l10);

    JLabel l11 = new JLabel("Gender:");
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l11, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l11);

    JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t1);

    JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t2, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t2);

    JTextField t3 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t3, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t3);

    JTextField t4 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t4, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t4);

    JTextField t5 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 5;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t5, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t5);

    JTextField t6 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridwidth = 3;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t6, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t6);

    JTextField t7 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 3;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t7, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t7);

    JTextField t8 = new JTextField();
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 3;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t8, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t8);

    JComboBox c1 = new JComboBox();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(c1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(c1);

    JSpinner s1 = new JSpinner();
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(s1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(s1);

    JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton();
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(r1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(r1);

    JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton();
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 5;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(r2, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(r2);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Clear");
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 6;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.ipadx = 5;
    constraints.ipady = 5;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(b1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(b1);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("Submit");
    constraints.gridx = 3;
    constraints.gridy = 6;
    constraints.gridwidth = 3;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.ipadx = 5;
    constraints.ipady = 5;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(b2, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(b2);

    JButton b3 = new JButton("Quit");
    constraints.gridx = 6;
    constraints.gridy = 6;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.ipadx = 5;
    constraints.ipady = 5;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(b3, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(b3);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(560,330);
    setResizable(false);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    new app("Info App").setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Current GUI:

[image: Current GUI]

Intended GUI: 
[image: Intended GUI]

I'm trying to align this  GridBagLayout in such a way that the text fields on the left half are equivalent in width to the once on the right. Additionally, is there a way to spread out the sides to fit better? Thanks.

Comment: For starters, pass the number of character columns you want to the constructor of `JTextField(int columns)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) method that is `implemented` in [`Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) class which is the sub-class of [`Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Miglayout? It has a lot of features shown in its cheat sheet that may be of use.

[MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com) 
[Mig cheat sheet](http://www.miglayout.com/cheatsheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

user te`xtfiled.setBounds()` pass the arguments for the alignment and height and width of your `textfiled` and also use `Dimension` class to set the size of the textfield
click this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) for Dimension class methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JTextField(int columns)` constructor to set a fixed size of columns for your `JTextFields`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can set the textfields to a default size:

```
textfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
```

or you could set the GridBagConstraints to fill:

```
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

next, if you want the items to spread to the sides, try setting your weightx and weighty to 1 instead of 0:

```
constraints.weightx = 1;
constraints.weighty = 1;
```

You should probably lose the insets if you work like this.
For more information about this try [the oracle documentation about gridbaglayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

I would also suggest setting a preffered size for the frame and making it unresizable:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
setResizable(false);
```

Last but not least: you don't have to set the constraints-values each time you add an object, they remain the same after adding something so setting them once is enough.
Furthermore you can simplify the adding procedure by using:

```
getContentPane().add(textfield, constraints);
```

Hope this answers your problem